# How to edit a freshly opened image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, I took a screenshot which I saved as a PNG in my Pictures folder. Next, I right clicked the image and selected "Open with other application" to open it with GIMP. When I select the Paint Brush tool and try to draw on it, nothing happens at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi JansthcirlU, Welcome to GD.SE! What are you trying to do with your image? Are you able to make the initial point with the pen tool? There are several videos on how to use the pen tool in GIMP. I would also suggest checking out the GIMP help doc for using the pen tool [Drawing Shapes with the Path Tool](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Drawing_Shapes/)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Paint Brush tool, but the Pencil tool doesn't work either. In fact, none of the tools do anything at all. I just wanted to open an image and draw some free form lines.

Comment: Hmm... first off, can you create an entirely new image and edit it?

Comment: You mean, open a new instance of GIMP and create a new image? In which case, no, I cannot.

Comment: You cannot go to "File -> New" to create a new document? Do not open GIMP with any file, start fresh and see if you can paint on a blank-white canvas. My only thought is your layer is somehow locked or you're right clicking instead of left-cling to paint the canvas.

Comment: Here's what I get: https://imgur.com/a/YILBClM, when I try to draw on it, my Paint Brush cursor freezes where I initially clicked, but dragging it around has no effect at all.

Comment: Or, if you prefer a screencap: https://imgur.com/a/0X37GhK (potato quality though)

Comment: Hard to answer this, also tech support is off-topic. I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps show the Tool Options dialog in a screenshot.

Comment: Since I'm not an avid GIMP user, I'll just go with @user287001's answer and do a hard reset. I've hardly customized GIMP so it won't be such a big deal.

Comment: Your screenshot and screen recording are both missing the all-important Tool options dialog (Windows>Dockable dialog>Tool options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not remotely solvable because we can see only what you show and that's not much of your system nor of your GIMP settings. I have only 2 things to try:

1. Reset tool options, You can reset all options of all tools to their default state with a single click

[image]

This is the general Preferences dialog. Resetting icon is also in Tool Options.

Do the same for input devices (see the main preference list)

2. Uninstall GIMP and install the newest stable version

Comment: I don't recall changing many settings as I don't use GIMP very much (as you may have guessed). I do recall having added a Wacom tablet and stylus to my input devices, so perhaps it suddenly stopped recognizing my mouse for some reason. I'll try resetting everything later today.

Comment: You have a drawing tablet is just a thing which cannot be seen remotely. You can reset input device options, too.